# Error building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension when build matplotlib in Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I try to install matplotlib from source, then I run into some very strange errors.

The log after run "python setup.py build":

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.x]
                python: yes [2.7.6 (default, Jan 15 2014, 13:39:04)  [GCC
                        4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]]
              platform: yes [darwin]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.9.0.dev-7f46687]
                   six: yes [six was not found.]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 1.5]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.1.1]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 17.1.1]
                   png: yes [version 1.5.17]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [using nose version 1.3.0]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
                qt4agg: no  [PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing, version 81008]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: yes [version 1.14]
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.02]
                 latex: yes [version 3.1415926]
               pdftops: no

running build
running build_py
copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/mpl-data
running build_ext
building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.5.2/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:7:
In file included from src/file_compat.h:4:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:23:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1760:
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: 
      "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by "          "#defining
      NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
 ^
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:7:
In file included from src/file_compat.h:4:
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:288:40: warning: 
      conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    return PyObject_CallFunction(open, "Os", filename, mode);
                                       ^
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_7f46687-py2.7-macosx-10.7-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h:296:37: warning: 
      conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    ret = PyObject_CallMethod(file, "close", NULL);
                                    ^
src/ft2font.cpp:191:46: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro
      invocation
    fh = npy_PyFile_Dup(py_file, (char *)"wb");
                                             ^
src/ft2font.cpp:191:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'npy_PyFile_Dup'
    fh = npy_PyFile_Dup(py_file, (char *)"wb");
         ^
src/ft2font.cpp:195:36: error: too few arguments provided to function-like macro
      invocation
    npy_PyFile_DupClose(py_file, fh);
                                   ^
src/ft2font.cpp:195:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'npy_PyFile_DupClose'
    npy_PyFile_DupClose(py_file, fh);
    ^
src/ft2font.cpp:2144:46: error: too few arguments provided to function-like
      macro invocation
    npy_PyFile_DupClose(def->py_file, def->fp);
                                             ^
src/ft2font.cpp:2144:5: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'npy_PyFile_DupClose'
    npy_PyFile_DupClose(def->py_file, def->fp);
    ^
src/ft2font.cpp:2181:51: error: too few arguments provided to function-like
      macro invocation
    if ((fp = npy_PyFile_Dup(py_file, (char *)"rb"))) {
                                                  ^
src/ft2font.cpp:2181:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'npy_PyFile_Dup'
    if ((fp = npy_PyFile_Dup(py_file, (char *)"rb"))) {
              ^
src/ft2font.cpp:2207:54: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is
      deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
            (data = PyObject_CallMethod(py_file_arg, "read", ""))) {
                                                     ^
src/ft2font.cpp:2207:62: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is
      deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
            (data = PyObject_CallMethod(py_file_arg, "read", ""))) {
                                                             ^
5 warnings and 8 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems to be a numpy problem. I tried to use an old version 1.5.1, which also got the similar problem. Is there anyway to fix it without reinstall everything? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should try with a newer version of Numpy.

Comment: It seems 1.9.0.dev is the newest version of numpy that I could get.

Comment: Problem solved by use the numpy version 1.8.0. It seems to have something to do with the numpy API...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've often found compiling Numpy, Scipy, and Matplotlib to be a pain on a Mac. I have had it work, but you can save yourself a lot of time by installing [Canopy Express](https://enthought.com/downloads/), which is free, and gives you a full Python environment with Scipy, Numpy, iPython, pandas, and several other useful packages.

Please note - I don't work for Enthought and I'm not trying to get you to spend money with them! But their free product has saved me hours of time debugging installation problems with these packages on a Mac. You may find it's worth looking into.